# MobileFirst 7.1 authentication Issue

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have issue in authentication in mobilefirst 7.1,

```
 platformSourcesVersion=7.1.0.00.20151130-1648
```

I have all my security tests, realms , login modules ... inserted correctly,

in my auth adapter i have :

```
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", null); 
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
```

after login when i invoke WL.Client.updateUserInfo(), and i getUserInfo from realm it returns NULL,

It's like server disconnect directly after login,

authentificationConfig.xml :

```
  http://pastebin.com/q6JSFDmU
```

Login in authentication-impl.js

```
http://pastebin.com/sz1dcnAG
```

ChallengeHandler :

```
 http://pastebin.com/q9BsdGbF
```

Any help ???

Thanks

Comment: How do we know you have everything really set-up correctly? How should we know that you're calling this code from the correct place in the adapter? Provide your code and setup.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that i had to turn a "true" to "false" in worklight.properties

```
 mfp.session.independent=false
```

:)